# Need to speed up writing large object graph to database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

I'm using EntityFramework Core on my current project.  In this project, I have an API endpoint that accepts a large (4,000K) text file.  The endpoint reads and parses the file and converting the data into an object graph.

I then need to write the entire graph to a SQL database.  After parsing the text file, I wind up with about 20,000 objects in this object graph.

The graph typically has one Transaction.  The Transaction has about 5000 Subscribers and each Subscriber has an average of 4 Benefits.  Each Dates collection will have 1 or 2 DateRanges.  Rejections are usually empty.

My object graph looks basically like this:

```
public class Transaction {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   ...  // Other properties
   public ICollection<Subscriber> Subscribers {get; private set;}
   public ICollection<TranRejection> Rejections {get; private set;}
}

public class Subscriber {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int TransactionId {get; set;}  //Foreign Key
   ... // Other properties
   public ICollection<Benefit> Benefits {get; private set;}
   public ICollection<SubscriberRejection> Rejections {get; private set;}
   public ICollection<SubscriberDateRange> Dates {get; private set;}
}

public class Benefit {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int SubscriberId {get; set;}  //Foreign Key
   ... // Other properties
   public ICollection<BenefitRejection> Rejections {get; private set;}
   public ICollection<BenefitDateRange> Dates {get; private set;}
}

//This abstract class w/ empty subclasses is done to take advantage of TPH
//so that all dates get stored in a single table
public abstract class DateRange {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int ParentId {get; set;}
   public string DateCode {get; set;}
   public DateTime BeginRange {get; set;}
   public DateTime? EndRange {get; set;}
}

public class BenefitDateRange : DateRange {}
public class SubscriberDateRange : DateRange {}

//Rejection class is handled very similar to DateRange
```

My EF Mappings look something like this.  (Only including important bits to help see relationships).

```
builder.Entity<DateRange>().ToTable("dateranges")
  .HasDiscriminator<string>("rangetype")
  .HasValue<BenefitDateRange>("benefit")
  .HasValue<SubscriberDateRange>("subscriber");
builder.Entity<DateRange>().HasKey(r => r.Id);

builder.Entity<Transaction>().HasMany(t => t.Subscribers).WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey(s => s.TransactionId);

builder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasMany(s => s.Benefits).WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey(b => b.SubscriberId);

builder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasMany(s => s.Dates).WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);

//Similar mappings for Benefit.Dates
//Rejections are using TPH just like DateRanges
```

I tried saving to the database by saving pieces individually -- i.e saving transaction with no subscribers and then saving each subscriber, etc.  That takes at least 30 minutes.

I then switched to saving the entire graph at once like this:

```
_dbContext.AddRange(transactions);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That takes about 5 minutes.  However, this is part of an API call and I'd like to speed this up.  Is there a faster way to save this whole graph to the database?  Should I not be using EF for this?

Comment: can you divide your objects into chunks and pass them to server parallel?

Comment: Bulk insert perhaps https://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=codeplex or https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools (not EF)

Comment: try Dapper if can? https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper-Plus/wiki/dapper-plus-bulk-insert

Comment: I'd do some profiling and see where your performance bottleneck really is, but I'd suspect that a large part of it is overhead from running a query per object. As @Magnus said, BulkInsert will go a long way towards curing that. Also, depending on how you're building the graph objects, garbage collection may be an issue.

Comment: @LeszekRepie OP specified EF core.

Comment: Turning of entity tracking might speed things up a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the demo version of [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=codeplex), I was able to get the 5 minute Insert time down to approx. 30 seconds!  Worked great -- of course, there is a $$ cost to going with that solution.  I literally added a using clause and one line of code and voila, it worked.

```
_context.AddRange(history);
//_context.SaveChanges(); <-- Previous Code
_context.BulkSavechanges();  //New Entity Framework Extensions Code
```

I tried EFCore.BulkExtensions.  I was unable to get this to work.  It didn't seem to like the Conversion mapping that I had created in my Fluent API Entity Map.

```
builder.Entity<Transaction>()
  .Property(t => t.Receiver)
  .HasColumnName("receiverdata")
  .HasConversion(v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v), v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceiverEntity>(v));
```

EFCore.BulkExtensions states that they support Conversion so I'm not sure what the issue is here.  I posted the [issue](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/115) on GitHub so we'll see if there is a way to get this to work or not.

Comment: Try `BulkInsert` instead of `BulkSavechanges` as it doesn't call `DetectChanges`

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem, but with one less level. The solution that worked best for us was to use BulkExtensions and wrap each level in a try-catch block and roll back all changes if there was an error saving.

https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

The native option without external libraries was to turn off AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled on the DBContext. But it was still a bit slower than using BuilExtensions.

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Our use case was to always insert new rows and not to update existing. So, I can't speak for the performance of `InsertOrUpdate` method of BulkExtensions. But, worth giving a try.

Comment: Does BulkExtensions use the EF defined relationships to map an object with all of its sub-objects or does it require you to re-define those relationships or manually BulkInsert child list properties, etc.?

Comment: As far as I remember, I had to manually define a db transaction and do a BulkInsert on each object explicitly. It wasn't smart enough to implicitly maintain the relationships. Also, had to set the SetOutputIdentity property to true which came in handy to setup the relationships.

Comment: That's a shame as I've already defined all the relationships via Fluent API.  Seems redundant to have to do that again -- especially when the extensions hang right off the DbContext where the relationship definitions exist.  Anyhow, thanks -- I'll look into this further.

Comment: Note that this library supports only SqlServer database. Other than that, it *does* use EF Core model metadata.

Comment: If you have it defined, yes its redundant. In my case I was not there yet, so it worked out. Like Ivan pointed, it works only with SQL Server (or Azure SQL)